# PostgreSQL return last row in each sequence of same column values (alternation)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

We are using PostgreSQL 10.23 database. We have the following table of test results:

| **id** | **test_result** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OK | test 1 |
| 2 | OK | test 2 |
| 3 | ERROR | test 3 |
| 4 | ERROR | test 4 |
| 5 | OK | test 5 |
| 6 | OK | test 6 |
| 7 | WARNING | test 7 |

We would like to return rows with the largest `id` for the sequence of the same consecutive `test_result` values. Our expected output is:

| **id** | **test_result** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | OK | test 2 |
| 4 | ERROR | test 4 |
| 6 | OK | test 6 |
| 7 | WARNING | test 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `lead()`:

```sql
select
    id, 
    test_result, 
    name
from (
    select 
        id, 
        test_result, 
        name,
        lead(test_result) over (order by id) as next_result
    from my_table
    ) s
where test_result is distinct from next_result;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/gTBtfAah)